# Scrollbar overlapping into footer

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a scrollbar in my app but there seems to be a bug. When I scroll and it gets to the bottom of the page it overlaps to the footer.

[Bug description photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGMlq.jpg)

This is the scrollbar css

```js
var changer = document.querySelector(".toc-wrapper");
var body = document.querySelector("body")

window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
  let scroll = this.scrollY;
  var place = window.location.href
  console.log('SCROLLY', scroll)

  if (place == "https://aqwzx-zksync-v2-docs--pr484-feat-doc-222-rs0trdzc.web.app/docs/api/api.html#zks-l1chainid") {
    changer.style.height = "50vh"
  } else if (scroll <= 21340) {
    changer.style.height = "70vh"
  }

  if (place == "https://aqwzx-zksync-v2-docs--pr484-feat-doc-222-rs0trdzc.web.app/docs/api/js/utils.html#undol1tol2alias" || place == "https://aqwzx-zksync-v2-docs--pr484-feat-doc-222-rs0trdzc.web.app/api/js/utils.html#sleep") {
    changer.style.height = "50vh"
  } else if (scroll <= 18560) {
    changer.style.height = "70vh"
  }

  if (place == "https://aqwzx-zksync-v2-docs--pr484-feat-doc-222-rs0trdzc.web.app/docs/api/js/accounts.html#getting-token-balance-on-l1-1" && scroll >= 13100) {
    changer.style.height = "50vh"
  } else if (scroll <= 13100) {
    changer.style.height = "70vh"
  }

  if (place == "https://aqwzx-zksync-v2-docs--pr484-feat-doc-222-rs0trdzc.web.app/docs/dev/developer-guides/aa.html#example-of-using-the-library" || place == "https://aqwzx-zksync-v2-docs--pr484-feat-doc-222-rs0trdzc.web.app/dev/developer-guides/aa.html#verifying-aa-signatures-within-our-sdk") {
    changer.style.height = "50vh"
  }

  if (place == "https://aqwzx-zksync-v2-docs--pr484-feat-doc-222-rs0trdzc.web.app/docs/dev/building-on-zksync/contracts/differences-with-ethereum.html#gasperpubdatabyte-should-be-taken-into-account-in-development") {
    changer.style.height = "50vh"
  }

  if (place == "http://localhost:8080/docs/dev/troubleshooting/faq.html#proof-sampling-on-testnet") {
    changer.style.height = "50vh"
  }

  if (place == "http://localhost:8080/docs/api/js/types.html#transactionresponse") {
    changer.style.height = "50vh"
  }
})
```

Comment: Make the `z-index` of the footer higher than the navigation so that it overlays, perhaps? The JS doesn't seem relevant to this UI issue.